# Understanding index scan in postgreSQL and random access concept

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I'm trying to understand how index scan's actually performed.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id = 46983
```

Consider the following plan:

```
Index Scan using pk_tbl on tbl  (cost=0.29..8.30 rows=1 width=1064) (actual time=0.012..0.013 rows=1 loops=1)
  Index Cond: (id = 46983)
Planning time: 0.101 ms
Execution time: 0.050 ms
```

As far as I undersdtand, the index scan process consists of two random page read. In my case

```
SHOW random_page_cost
```

returns `4`.

So, I guess we need to find the block the the row with `id = 46983` stored in (random access in index) and then we need to read that block by it's address(random access the block in physical storage). That's clear, two random access are actually occured. But from [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_access) I read that

> In data structures, direct access implies the ability to access any
>   entry in a list in ***constant time***

But it's obviously that traversing the balanced-tree doesn't have constant-time complexity, because it depends on the deep of the tree.

That way, how come is it correct to say that requesting the block of the index is actually random-access?

Comment: Fetching one page is always random access. This one page could be the first page of a "sequential" file or of any other file. A "sequential file" actually does not exist, but in most cases the OS (or disk-driver, or disk-controller) *assumes* that the "next" block will be needed too. For "random" files, the second block requested will be a bit *more* random. And, in both cases: the blocks could have been stored in disk-cache buffers, making the access very cheap.

Comment: @joop _Fetching one page is always random access_. But if we don't have any index, the planner will have to perform `seq scan`, so there will be the sequential access, not the random one.

Comment: With respect to the index-height: in fact you are right. In practice, the difference is neglected, an index is only a few levels deep (~= constant factor) , and only the leaf pages are counted.

Comment: @joop Also, my question is not exavtly what you're talking about. I'm a bit confused by the definition of the radmon access itself. It requires having the constant time to access each elelmnt in the structure. But, the balanced-tree structure doesn't provide us with the constant time access.

Comment: @joop So, since the deep of an index grows logariphmically, we can assume that it's almost constant. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @joop BTW, it isn't directly related to the question, but don't you know what `0.30` means in the total cost `8.30`? `8.00` means two random access, as I've already found out.

Comment: Fetching *the first page* of a "sequential" file is just as random as fetching the first page for any other file. The difference is in the next pages (and the inner workings of the underlying OS/FS) (... and the number of neeeded pages, of course)

Comment: Note: the cost calculations are done in *arbitrary units*, assumed to be (linearly) related to the actual "cost". And *cost* is a weighted sum of diverse factors: {disk,memory,IO,CPU}- resources, -->> time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that indexes in database are normally stored as B-trees or [B+trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%2B_tree), an *n*-ary tree structure with a variabile but very large number of children per node. A typical tree of this kind with three or four levels can address millions of records, and almost certainly at least the root is kept in the cache (buffer pool), so that a typical access for a random key has a cost in the order of 1 or 2 disk accesses. For this reason, in the database field (and when costs are estimated) the access to a B-tree index is considered as a small constant.

Comment: In simple words, we can assume that the tree has a constant lenght, because of it grows very slowly, right?

Comment: BTW, couldn't you explain what  `0.30 ` means in the total cost  `8.30 `?

Comment: Exactly, the cost is estimated as practically constant. For what concern the 0.30, this is the estimated start-up cost of the operation (as the documentation says: "This is the time expended before the output phase can begin, e.g., time to do the sorting in a sort node"). Note the the unit of cost is the number of disk pages fetches, but can be changed with `seq_page_cost`, for instance to take into considerations SSD vs. hard disks. A detailed description of the `explain` is reported in the [PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/using-explain.html).